# Spring Security, OAUTH2, dynamic client-secret

Tags: spring-security, oauth

Spring Security version 5.4.0

Usually client-id and client-secret are values supplied by Oauth2 provider and they are permanent for each client and can be specified in the configuration file like this

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: google-client-id
            client-secret: google-client-secret
```

But in my case I have fixed client-id but client-secret is generated based on some parameters by every attempt to get authentication code.
In the final class `ClientRegistration` the client-secret is defined as a string value, so it is not possible to adopt this class in my case

My question whether it it possible to use Spring Security in such conditions and if yes, what could be adopted/configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be doing [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).

In that case, [you can leave the secret empty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#initiating-the-authorization-request) and Spring Security will generate the code challenge and verifier as part of the `/authorize` request.

From the docs:

> Public Clients are supported using Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE). If the client is running in an untrusted environment (eg. native application or web browser-based application) and therefore incapable of maintaining the confidentiality of its credentials, PKCE will automatically be used when the following conditions are true:
>
> `client-secret` is omitted (or empty)
>
> `client-authentication-method` is set to `"none"` (`ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE`)

If you are doing something custom, then you might consider standardizing to PKCE.

But, if you can't do that, then Spring Security ships with various hooks for [adding custom parameters to the `/authorize`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#customizing-the-authorization-request) and [`/token` requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#customizing-the-access-token-request). I'd recommend taking a look at `DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver#setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer` and `DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient#setRequestEntityConverter`.

You can register your custom authorization request and token request in the DSL like so:

```java
http
    .oauth2Login((oauth2) -> oauth2
        .authorizeEndpoint((authorize) -> authorize
            .authorizeRequestResolver(...)
        )
        .tokenEndpoint((token) -> token
            .accessTokenResponseClient(...)
        )
    );
```